# Remove space between elements in html/css (ionic)

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

Im trying to remove the blank space between these 2 elements, in ionic.

Here is the HTML:

```
<link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css" />
<ion-view name="tab-suppliers">
  <ion-content>

    <h2 class="no-padding bg-lightblue font-white tb-header"><center>TITLE!</center></h2>

    <div class="row text-center bg-lightblue font-white test">
      <div class="col col-25">
        TEST
      </div>
      <div class="col col-25">
        TEST
      </div>
      <div class="col col-25">
        TEST
      </div>
      <div class="col col-25">
        TEST
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And here is the css:

```
.bg-lightblue {
  background-color: #99CEFF;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.font-white {
  color: white;
}

.tb-header {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}


.test {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Ain't .test class is supposed to remove the blank space between the elements? If not, could someone explain me why?

What is the properly way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<h2>` element has a default `bottom-margin` which causing the space between your `<h2>` and `<div>`. So you have to remove this margin. See the following example:

```css
.bg-lightblue {
  background-color: #99CEFF;
}
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
.font-white {
  color: white;
}
.tb-header {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<ion-view name="tab-suppliers">
  <ion-content>
    <h2 class="no-padding bg-lightblue font-white tb-header"><center>TITLE!</center></h2>
    <div class="row text-center bg-lightblue font-white test">
      <div class="col col-25">
        TEST
      </div>
      <div class="col col-25">
        TEST
      </div>
      <div class="col col-25">
        TEST
      </div>
      <div class="col col-25">
        TEST
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: That's it! Awnser approved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

/* should target any .row immediately proceeded by an <h2> */
h2 ~ .row {
  padding-top: 0;
}
```